# How to add an image from the video to the beginning of composition? (Just an image, not a clip)

Tags: video, after-effects

I have a composition which is a union of 2 composition, and I want to add a snapshot from the composition to the beginning of it - is there any shortcut for it?

I tried searching for it Google but did not find relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu (at the top or by right-clicking a layer) choose **Layer>Time>Freeze Frame**

Adobe have a user's guide, it's a good place to start. [Read more here](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/time-stretching-time-remapping.html).